# What is the double pipes in Ruby ( not the ||= )?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain to me what the double pipes, `|i|`, represent or are called in this example?

```
(1..10).detect {|i| (1..10).include?(i * 3)}
```

Comment: This is basic Ruby and is covered in any decent Ruby book or tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

That's the syntax to declare the *block parameters* in Ruby.

Read the [Cycling and Looping—a.k.a. Iteration](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/)

> Let’s look at that iterator in more depth:

```
@names.each do |name|
  puts "Hello #{name}!"
end
```

> `#each` is a method that accepts a block of code then runs that block of code for every element in a list, and the bit between do and end is just such a block. A block is like an anonymous function or lambda. *The variable between **pipe** characters is the parameter for this block.*

Answer (score 0):

They are syntax for parameters for blocks or Procs in Ruby.